# Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) input shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to CNN and I have a question regarding CNN. I am a bit confused about the input shape of CNN (specifically with Keras).
My data is a 2D data (let's say 10X10) in different time slots. Therefore, I have 3D data.
I am going to feed this data to my model to predict the coming time slot. So, I will have a certain number of time slots for prediction (let's say 10 slots, so far, I may have a 10X10X10 data).
Now, my question is that I have to deal with this data as a 2D image with 10 channels (like ordinary kinds of data in CNN, RGB images) or as a 3D data. (conv2D or conv3D in Keras).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You be better trying seq2seq or rnn networks rather than simple cnn.

Comment: I don't think seq2seq or RNN works in my case. I would prefer to stick to CNN or CNN-LSTM. Thank you though.

Comment: Because your data seems to have only one color channel (not RGB, but simply just 10-by-10 pixels), I think Conv2D should suffice. If you set the number of color channels equal to 1, I think the Conv2D operation might in fact be identical to that performed by a Conv3D layer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your case,`Conv2D` will be useful. Please refer below description for understanding input shape of Convolution Neural Network (CNN) using `Conv2D`.

Let’s see how the input shape looks like. The input data to CNN will look like the following picture. We are assuming that our data is a collection of images.

[image]

Input shape has `(batch_size, height, width, channels)`. Incase of `RGB` image would have a channel of `3` and the `greyscale` image would have a channel of `1`.

Let’s look at the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D

model=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, input_shape=(10,10,3)))
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 10, 10, 64)        256       
=================================================================
```

Thought it looks like out input shape is `3D`, but you have to pass a `4D` array at the time of fitting the data which should be like `(batch_size, 10, 10, 3)`. Since there is no batch size value in the input_shape argument, we could go with any batch size while fitting the data.

The output shape is `(None, 10, 10, 64)`. The first dimension represents the batch size, which is `None` at the moment. Because the network does not know the batch size in advance.

`Note:` Once you fit the data, `None` would be replaced by the batch size you give while fitting the data.

Let’s look at another code with batch Size

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D

    model=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, batch_input_shape=(16,10,10,3)))
    model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (16, 10, 10, 64)          256       
=================================================================
```

Here I have replaced `input_shape` argument with `batch_input_shape`. As the name suggests, this argument will ask you the batch size in advance, and you can not provide any other batch size at the time of fitting the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped.

Comment: @Hamed, If I have answered your question, can you please accept the answer and upvote the answer. Thank You