# Set batch size of trained keras model to 1

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am having a keras model trained on my own dataset. However after loading weights the summary shows None as the first dimension(the batch size).

I want to know the process to fix the shape to batch size of 1, as it is compulsory for me to fix it so i can convert the model to tflite with GPU support.

Comment: Instead of using `input_shape` to feed the model and train, use `batch_input_shape` and choose required `batch_size`. For more information you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61075207/14290681). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to specify batch size to the Input layer, like this:

```
input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape, batch_size=1, dtype='float32', name='images')
```

This then carried through the rest of the layers.

The bad news is that despite this "fix" the tfl runtime still complains about dynamic tensors. I get these non-fatal errors in logcat when it runs:

```
E/tflite: third_party/tensorflow/lite/core/subgraph.cc:801 tensor.data.raw != nullptr was not true.
E/tflite: Attempting to use a delegate that only supports static-sized tensors with a graph that has dynamic-sized tensors (tensor#26 is a dynamic-sized tensor).
E/tflite: Ignoring failed application of the default TensorFlow Lite delegate indexed at 0.
```

The good news is that despite these errors it seems to be using the GPU anyway, based on performance testing.

I'm using:

```
tensorflow-lite-support:0.2.0'    
tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.2.1'    
tensorflow-lite:2.6.0'    
tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.3.0'
```

Hopefully, they'll fix the runtime so it doesn't matter whether the batch size is 'None'. It shouldn't matter for doing inference.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and cannot find solution anywhere. However, I managed to solve it with some workaround.

Firstly, you need to get config of your model:

```
model.get_config()
```

There you see a `batch_input_shape`

```
{'name': 'sequential',
 'layers': [{'class_name': 'InputLayer',
   'config': {'batch_input_shape': (None, 28, 28, 1),
    'dtype': 'float32',
    'sparse': False,
    ...
```

Next, you need to change the `None` value to desired batch size. For example like this (changing to 1):

```
for layer in conf['layers']:
    if 'batch_input_shape' in layer['config']:
        shape = layer['config']['batch_input_shape']
        shape = (1, *shape[1:])
        layer['config']['batch_input_shape'] = shape
```

Now the config dict should look like this:

```
{'name': 'sequential',
 'layers': [{'class_name': 'InputLayer',
   'config': {'batch_input_shape': (1, 28, 28, 1),
    'dtype': 'float32',
    'sparse': False,
    ...
```

And the final step is to create a model from the new config and set weights from initial model.

```
new_model = model.from_config(conf)
new_model.set_weights(model.get_weights())
```

Looking at summary, we see it worked:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                  Output Shape            Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)               (1, 26, 26, 32)         320       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)  (1, 13, 13, 32)         0
```